# What are good resources for getting started with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resources

jQuery and JavaScript in general are new ground for me.

What are some good resources to get me up and running.

I am particularly interested in page manipulation - eg moving elements about programmatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/) would be a good start (especially the [Manipulation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) section). Usually lots of good examples as well as the documentation.

I picked up [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) which was well-worth a read.

Comment: You beat me to it, docs.jquery.com is actually pretty good.

Comment: I was pleasantly surprised, yes. It over-delivered, IMO.

Comment: Really?  I despise jQuery documentation.  I find it hard to believe that MSDN spoiled me, but apparently its true...

Comment: Just an example... Its impossible to find a concise list of selectors that covers the grammar in any acceptable way with good examples.

Comment: @Will - it is a little terse, maybe, but it is enough to get the idea. Maybe it helps that I read "jQuery in Action" before I saw "docs.jquery.com", so most of the fundamentals had already been explained.

Comment: I highly agree with this post.  docs.jquery.com is a fountain of knowledge, some of the best documentation I've seen around.  +1

Answer (score 3):

docs.jquery.com is the obvious choice however there are some great tutorials out there [jQuery for designers](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/) is one of the best.

However if your looking to really jump in and learn it all quickly and hands on (which i suggest) I highly recommend the firebug console and [Visual jQuery](http://visualjquery.com/) and start tinkering away best way to learn IMHO, good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Learning jQuery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847192505) and [jQuery Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847193811).  The first book is good to get your started with a lot of examples, especially about selecting all kinds of elements.  The second is good for quickly looking up a property or method.

Answer (score 3):

[Visual jQuery](http://visualjquery.com/) is a more pleasant way of browsing the jQuery documentation...

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice cheat sheet here: http://www.gscottolson.com/jquery/jQuery1.2.cheatsheet.v1.0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to a free 10 day trial  of
  [safaribooksonline](http://www.safaribooksonline.com)

You should be able to read the jQuery in Action book till your trial runs out. By then you should know if the book is any good and it should of got you up to speed with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cheat sheets on the Alternative resource page (http://docs.jquery.com/Alternative_Resources) to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Designers Wall](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/) has a good introduction.